# How does d3.svg.diagonal() read bound data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am in the process of learning d3.js right now, and as I am going through a few tutorials, I find that I am just really confused as to how commands like d3.svg.diagonal() are able to access bound data. Take the example below:

```
 var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('width', 500)
        .attr('height', 500)
        .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(50,50)');

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([400,400]);


    var data = {
        'name':'Max',
        'children': [
            {
                'name':'Sylvia',
                'children': [
                    {'name': 'Craig'},
                    {'name': 'Robin'},
                    {'name': 'Anna'}
                ]
            },
            {
                'name': 'David',
                'children': [
                    {'name': 'Jeff'},
                    {'name': 'Buffy'}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    var nodes = tree.nodes(data);
    var links = tree.links(nodes);

    var node = canvas.selectAll('.node')
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr('transform', function(d){ return 'translate(' + d.x +','+ d.y+')';});

    node.append('circle')
        .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
        .attr('r', 5);

    node.append('text')
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal();

    var link = canvas.selectAll('link')
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
            .attr('class', 'link')
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', '#ADADAD')
            .attr('d', diagonal)
```

I can see that the line 'var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()' is a function that will create "diagonal" paths, but when I am setting attributes for the .link class-named elements I am creating, I do not see how '.attr("d", diagonal);' ever gets access to the data I bound with '.data(links)'. Maybe if it were actually called as a function with 'd' passed to it, but as it stands, I do not see where diagonal ever gets access to the data. I don't think it is connected with the tree layout, because it is never passed the variable 'diagonal' either. Can someone help me wrap my head around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
.attr("d", diagonal)
```

is in this case equivalent to

```
.attr("d", function(d, i) { return diagonal(d, i); })
```

You're passing the function `diagonal()` to the `.attr()` call in the first case. In the second case the same thing happens except that the function you pass is anonymous (i.e. it doesn't have a name) and calls `diagonal()` inside.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#attr):

> [I]f value is a function, then the function is evaluated for each selected element (in order), being passed the current datum d and the current index i, with the this context as the current DOM element.

So by passing the named function `diagonal()`, it automatically gets the data bound to the elements in the selection.

Comment: Gotcha. So the function diagonal does not actually need to be called when it is passed. Didn't know you could do that in javascript!

Comment: In both cases you're passing a function. To call a function, you need to explicitly put `()` (or whatever the argument list is) after the name, otherwise you're referring to the unevaluated function object.

Comment: I guess to rephrase what I meant - I didn't realize you could just pass a function without the () to have it evaluate. In this case it sounds like d3.js has some code explicitly written to tell the function what to do in that situation, but in general, I had never considered that you might be able to do that.

Comment: All D3 does is call the function that's passed in with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Yeah, it's a cool idea. Seems obvious now lol. Thanks for breakin it down for me man